# Embedded Kafka not showing consumer offset

Tags: kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, embedded-kafka

Got an embedded kafka instance running as part of a test.
I'm trying to verify that all the messages have been read but am getting an empty result from the kafka admin client.

```
Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata> partitionOffset = embeddedKafkaRule.getEmbeddedKafka().doWithAdminFunction(admin -> {
        try{
            return admin.listConsumerGroupOffsets(COUNTER_GROUP).partitionsToOffsetAndMetadata().get();
        }catch (Exception e){
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    });
```

The map is always empty.
I've tried setting ack all and having 100ms autoOffsetCommit with a wait to see if this makes any difference but no luck.

```
 System.setProperty("spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.brokers", embeddedKafkaRule.getEmbeddedKafka()
            .getBrokersAsString());
 System.setProperty("spring.cloud.stream.bindings.enricher-in-0.destination", COUNTER_TOPIC);
 System.setProperty("spring.cloud.stream.bindings.enricher-in-0.group", COUNTER_GROUP);
 System.setProperty("spring.cloud.stream.bindings.enricher-out-0.destination", ENRICHED_COUNTER_TOPIC);
 System.setProperty("spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.enricher-in-0.consumer.ackEachRecord", "true");
 System.setProperty("spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.enricher-in-0.autoCommitOffset", "true");       System.setProperty("spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.commit.interval.ms", "100");
```

Answer (score 0):

When are you setting those system properties? Are you sure the binding is using the embedded broker?

This works fine for me.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So65329718Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So65329718Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    Consumer<String> consume() {
        return System.out::println;
    }

}
```

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.consume-in-0.group=theGroup
```

```java
@SpringBootTest
@EmbeddedKafka(bootstrapServersProperty = "spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers")
class So65329718ApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    KafkaTemplate<byte[], byte[]> template;

    @Autowired
    EmbeddedKafkaBroker broker;

    @Test
    void test() throws InterruptedException {
        this.template.send("consume-in-0", "foo".getBytes());
        Thread.sleep(10_000);
        this.broker.doWithAdmin(admin -> {
            try {
                System.out.println(admin.listConsumerGroupOffsets("theGroup").partitionsToOffsetAndMetadata()
                        .get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
            }
            catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

```
foo
...
{consume-in-0-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=1, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}}
```

(The binder uses `spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers` if there is no binder-specific property).

Comment: I'm sure it's using the embedded instance as I can query for consumer groups and they show up. I'm also able to see the output on the output topic after my app has processed the messages on the inbound topic. They only big difference I can see is in using the embedded Kafka classrule rather than annotation and autowiring.

Comment: That will make no difference; something else is going on. If you can provide a complete, simple, example project I can take a look to see what's wrong.